# why different XPathFactory implementation used?

Tags: java, xpath

My java web application works in local development environment, but fails in SIT environment.

local development environment：JDK7 + Jetty

```
JAXP: Looking up system property 'javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom'
JAXP: The property is undefined.
JAXP: found null in $java.home/jaxp.properties
JAXP: attempting to use the platform default W3C DOM XPath lib
JAXP: factory 'com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl' was found for http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
JAXP: using thread context class loader (WebAppClassLoader=iFinBMS@5501d1c8) for search
```

SIT environment：JDK7+WebLogic10.3.6

```
JAXP: Looking up system property 'javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom'
JAXP: The property is undefined.
JAXP: found null in $java.home/jaxp.properties
JAXP: no META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory file was found
JAXP: attempting to use the platform default W3C DOM XPath lib
JAXP: instanciating org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl
JAXP: failed to instanciate org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl
```

why JAXP try to use `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl` in local environment, but `org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl` in sit environment, what's causing this difference?